# Check if input email is a valid company email

Tags: javascript, php, email, sanitization

Is there any email checking API that I can use to verify if an email is a company email and not a personal one?

1. I want to **not accept** @gmail @yahoo @bing @aol @any_other_public_providers
2. I want to **accept** valid company emails
3. I want to **not accept** emails that are non existent @inexistentdomain

I was also considering pinging on port 25 the host of the email but in this case @gmail, will still reply positive, even though its a public provider.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

I have found this [PHP SMTP Email Validation](https://code.google.com/p/php-smtp-email-validation/).

It uses SMTP to query the domain if the email server exists.

Now I suppose the only option to verify if the email is a company one is to query a database of company emails for existence OR deny the most popular public email providers.

Have found a list of [public email providers](https://gist.github.com/tbrianjones/5992856).

Comment: If your database is small, check if email exist in your database or not before sending email. Else use [Regex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to check if the email id belongs to company or not. You possibly can't deny every public domain out there.